# Parsing a substring without allocating it separately

Tags: d

I have a `string` containing a nondigit followed by digits. For example:

```
string s = "A42";
```

How do I obtain a `char` (containing the nondigit) and an `int` (obtained by parsing the digits) from this `string`, without allocating a second temporary string?

```
char c = 'A';
int i = 42;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slice of the string is an allocation of two pointers into the original string (or a pointer and a length), as normal for D arrays. So this is enough:

```
char c = s[0];
int i = to!int(s[1..$]);
```